# How to parse a Struct from SoapClient->__getTypes()?

Tags: php, parsing, soap, struct

I am trying to parse the types of WSDL using the getTypes():

```
$wsdl  = 'http://wwwh1.tjrj.jus.br/HMNI/Servico.svc?singleWsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$types = $client->__getTypes();
foreach($types as $type){
   var_dump($type);
}
```

However the result are "Strings" like that:

```
string 'struct tipoConsultarAvisosPendentes {
 string idRepresentado;
 string idConsultante;
 string senhaConsultante;
 string dataReferencia;
}' (length=136)
```

I would like to get **each attributes** (and its types). 
Is there another method to parse the types?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I did myself:

```
function parseSoapTypes(\SoapClient $soap): array {
    $types = $soap->__getTypes();
    $types_parsed = [];
    $regex = '/^\s(\w*?)\s(\w*?);/mi';
    $regex_struct = '/struct\s(.*?)\s/';
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        preg_match($regex_struct, $type, $match_struct);
        $struct = isset($match_struct[1]) ? $match_struct[1] : [];
        preg_match_all($regex, $type, $matches);
        if (isset($matches[1]) && isset($match_struct[1])) {
            $types_parsed[$struct] = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);
        }
    }
    return $types_parsed;
}
```

Comment: wow, nice work, this saved me a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been 8 months, you probably don't need it anymore.
Posting for anyone else in this situation.

I personally used this tool [wsdl2phpgenerator](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)

You can inspect the source code and extract the part that parses the types if you only need that.